# check if item contain in list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of installed programs
With `Debug.writeLine` I can see in the output that there is a discord item.
**result.PackageName** It can be Discrod, Discord PTB or Discord Canary.

```
foreach (var installedItem in _installedApps)
{
  if (installedItem.DisplayName.Contains("Discord"))
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(installedItem.DisplayName);
    Debug.WriteLine(result.PackageName);
  }

  if (installedItem.DisplayName.Trim().Contains(result.PackageName.Trim()))
  {
    isInstalled = true;
  }
  else
  {
   isInstalled = false;
  }
}
```

But the code does not work and always returns false

UPDATE:

If I use the following code

```
var installedStatus = _installedApps.Where(x => x.DisplayName != null && result.PackageName != null && x.DisplayName.Contains(result.PackageName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Any();
```

And in the list of _installedApps, there is only one item named **Discord PTB** And also in the loop, which is the PackageName Discrod, Discrod PTB or Discrod Canary.

I have a false report that both versions are installed Only PTB should have an installation report.

But if I use the following code

```
                                var installedStatus = _installedApps.Where(x => x.DisplayName != null && result.PackageName != null && result.PackageName.Contains(x.DisplayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(x => x.Version);
```

I have the correct report, but the problem is that other programs are not detected

Comment: Debugging should show you where it fails and you should get an impression why it fails. Should be far faster then letting us do guess work. A guess you have a problem with casing while comparing strings. Contains has a second STringComparision parameter to control how to compare strings.

Comment: To be honest i don't really understand your update, do you mean you miss the `Debug.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because `isInstalled` is getting set by ever iteration.
So the last `installedItem` can set the value to false.
in essence this is `isInstalled` is only relevant to the last item.
If you want to use this code just remove the else.

if you want to use linq i would do it like this

```
isInstalled = _installedApps.Any(i=>i.DisplayName.Trim().Contains(result.PackageName.Trim()))
```

Comment: thank you, i updated my question can you take a look please?